# how to popup a webform in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference a website usercontrol in the c# windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896706/how-to-reference-a-website-usercontrol-in-the-c-windows-application)

I have a c# windows application in which i have 1 .aspx webform. I kept this form because the functionality was possible only on webform.now i want to popup that form on clicking a button in one of the forms. how to do it?

Comment: What kind of functionality is only possible with webforms?

Comment: You may be interested in this similar question - [Standalone MVC3 webapp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762193/standalone-mvc3-webapp/6762474#6762474)

Comment: @pavan - even tho I've answered this question I'm voting to close because I think the response you got to yesterday's *almost identical question* is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Another Update* - I just voted to close one of your other dupe questions which you posted after this one - and then I look through your question list and find this one from yesterday: [How to reference a website usercontrol in the c# windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896706/how-to-reference-a-website-usercontrol-in-the-c-windows-application) which is basically asking the same thing - only slightly differently; I'm just not sure whether to vote to close this one, that one, or delete my answer.  Please help us by showing that you listen to us - do not spam us!  Please either delete this question, that question - or accept that you're ***probably going to have to rewrite the user control***

Interesting - almost impossible too - however, how about using the IIS hostable web core as [this guy shows in his blog](http://www.awesomeideas.net/page/IIS7-Hostable-WebCore.aspx).

[MSDN Blog about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/hostyourownwebserverusingiis7.aspx)

[MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689327(v=vs.90).aspx)

Using this you can turn your forms app into a web server as well - in which you can run html, ASPX pages etc as if it was a 'proper' web server.

However - I'm not sure how much data is shared between the app and the IIS host - it's something I've been thinking about trying out for a while now but never got round to it.

*Edit* As @Kragen has pointed out in comments below - the possibility of being able to use this solution is very limited - due to pre-requisites etc.

Ultimately your best bet is going to be to rewrite that page into your form app - definitely for maintainability but even if just from a user's point of view - I would be seriously wondering why I have to use a web page for some stuff and not for others.

Comment: Neat, however "Requires IIS7 to be installed" and there isn't yet a redistributable for IIS Express - this makes it difficult to produce an end-user application that uses this.

Comment: @Kragen - very true; not out of the question for Windows 7/2008R2 deployments AND when it's an internal app; but really the answer is to rewrite the ASPX page functionality into the form app, except I didn't want to put that and seem like I was being really unhelpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at [Manos](http://jacksonh.tumblr.com/post/1159500924/manos-de-mono-the-manifesto), but you'll have to rewrite the aspx page for it.